# Error on account email - No SSH Key found

Tags: ssh, email

I am using Ubuntu Core 16 - raspberry pi 3 - for the first time, and in the installation I could not go through the validation stage of the email. I have already created an account in ubuntu one, but when I put the email the following message appears: "creating user failed: error: while creating user: can not create user for" danilogo@gmail.com: no ssh keys found " And I can access this account normally.

Thanks a lot for the help. =)

Comment: What Ubuntu version have you installed? Where exactly are you putting the email address and what for?

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to install ubuntu-core-16-pi3 - The error occurs in the first boot of the installation - I tried to follow this manual of the page, but I can not get past the part requesting the email and have no option to ignore This step.Page where I got the installation manual and download links - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/

Comment: If so, please edit your question and add all the info in your comment. Have you followed the instructions to generate an SSH key and have you imported it as mentioned in the prerequisites? Your reported error suggests you din't.

Comment: Okay, the question has already been edited. It turns out that I can not get past step 3 - where it asks for the email from the store account - or what's on my Ubuntu SSO credentials page. What I understand is that it would be the same email that I use in the account that I generated in Ubuntu One, but when I inform this email the error mentioned above appears.

Comment: The questions were: *Have you followed the instructions to generate an SSH key and have you imported it as mentioned in the prerequisites?* Again, that error suggests you didn't. Those are prerequisites, there's no way around it.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I thought I needed to get the key after installing ubuntu and importing it on the site. I did not know this needed to be done sooner. Now that you've spoken twice I tried to do this procedure and it worked. Sorry to bother with a simple thing, but it's the first time I start using this system and I'm trying to learn on my own. Thank you very much again. Thanks a Lot =)

Answer (score 6):

Documentation should look like this

1. Create SSH keys on "putty key generator" (PAGE: winscp.net/eng/download.php#download2)
   (The windows is in Tools/Run PuttyGen, you can see it PAGE: winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen#obtaining_and_starting_puttygen)
2. Copy generated keys to your account (Ubuntu SSO)
3. Run Raspberry Ubuntu Core and log in with Ubuntu SSO login and password (keys will automaticly download from your Ubuntu SSO account)
4. Start Putty and log in with private key https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-windows/
5. There is possibility to log in remotely. It is possible to log in directly from Raspberry Pi but you should change root password before.

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=175305

Answer (score 1):

I had misunderstood and thought I would need to get the ssh key after installing the system, but in fact I only needed to import a key into my account on ubuntu one and so during installation this key would be used. Thank you - CelticWarrior that made me reread all the instructions of the prerequisite and pay attention to this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that the SSH key needs to be generated and imported into Ubuntu1 but how is this done when you are stuck in the install wizard? I can't get out of it to get to a command line...

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl+C`. Please add some more info in you question

Comment: You need to do it somewhere else. In a putty session on Windows or a Terminal on Macos X. Just run the command (e.g. ssh-keygen -t rsa in Macos X), save it to a file, then open the file, copy the content and paste it in the Ubuntu one section). Super annoying!